# How to build google test with hidden visibility

Tags: cmake, visibility

When I build unit tests for a library (which is built with hidden visibility), I encounter about 400 warnings of this format:

```cpp
direct access in function 'testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<MyTestSuite>::GetTearDownCaseOrSuite(char const*, int)' from file 'libgtestd.a(gtest-all.o)' to global weak symbol 'testing::Test::TearDownTestSuite()' from file 'test_filemame.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

By changing the googletest's option `gtest_hide_internal_symbols` from `OFF` to `ON`, the number of warnings greatly decrease. However, I still have some warnings of this type:

```cpp
direct access in function 'testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<testing::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FailureTest>::GetTearDownCaseOrSuite(char const*, int)' from file 'libgtestd.a(gtest-all.o)' to global weak symbol 'testing::Test::TearDownTestCase()' from file 'test_mytest.o' means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely caused by different translation units being compiled with different visibility settings.
```

Can someone explain why the warnings still exist, when I already turn on `gtest_hide_internal_symbols` option? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about GTest, but I have seen these warnings from LD.

You probably receive all of these warnings for sub-modules or dependencies, wherein `gtest_hide_internal_symbols` is **not** turned on.

My guess is that `gtest_hide_internal_symbols` controls the GCC/LLVM option `-fvisiblility`. Specifically, turning `gtest_hide_internal_symbols` to `ON` probably sets `-fvisibility=hidden`.

**UPDATE:**

My assumption was correct.

See https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/830fb567285c63ab5b5873e2e8b02f2249864916/googletest/CMakeLists.txt#L80.

> ```
> if (gtest_hide_internal_symbols)
>   set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
>   set(CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN 1)
> endif()
> ```

`CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET` specifies `-fvisibility` and `CMAKE_VISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN` specifies `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`.

Comment: I do not get what you mean :) Can you please elaborate why given the block of code above, I see the warnings? 
Do you know what should I do to completely remove LD warnings from GTest?

Comment: You get those warnings because your code and the libraries it depends on have been compiled with different visibility settings. You'll want to match the `-fvisibility` option across everything compiled.

Comment: Here's more about symbol visibility: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: @no_name Did my answer help you? Never heard back.